# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n}$$

Evaluation: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^x t^{n-1} dt = \int_0^x \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{n-1}\right)dt = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1-t} dt= \log\left|1-x\right|$$

**My question:** Why is the integral being calculated on $[0,x]$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $\int_0^x t^{n-1} dt = \frac{x^n}{n}$.

Comment: Right... Thank you @Arthur!

Answer (score 1):

Because

$\int t^{n-1} dt = \frac{t^{n}}{n}$

and thus

$\int_0^x t^{n-1} dt = \frac{x^{n}}{n} - \frac{0^{n}}{n} = \frac{x^{n}}{n}$

which allows that neat little substitution.